# Xubuntu 16.04 Rhythmbox won't quit just keeps restarting

Tags: rhythmbox

I can't stop rhythmbox once it is started. I use quit, CTRL-W, kill -9, killall but nothing works. Every time rhythmbox gets restarted by an upstart (/sbin/upstart --user) process.

```
brian     2727  3620  1 16:02 ?        00:00:09 /usr/bin/rhythmbox

brian     3620  3385  0 13:29 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/upstart --user
```

When checking to see the service status I get the response that rhythmbox is not a service.

Comment: I don't use it but I see rhythmbox has a client-server system, how are you starting it, are you using a client? Won't the client start a new server if one isn't found? `ps aux | grep rhythmbox` should show the client process and the server. Perhaps try killing the client first?

Comment: Before I start rhythmbox  there is no rhythmbox processes running. `code` ps -aux | grep rhythmbox
brian    21181  0.0  0.0   6328   844 pts/3    S+   22:36   0:00 grep --color=auto rhythmbox
After starting rythmbox the only process running is rhthymbox `code` brian    21567 77.1  3.0 313664 126944 ?       Rl   22:36   0:09 rhythmbox
brian    21761  0.0  0.0   6328   840 pts/3    S+   22:36   0:00 grep --color=auto rhythmbox

Comment: Sorry not sure how this silly formatting works. Before I start rhythmbox there are no instances.  After starting there is only the one instance shown as just the name rhythmbox and after I quit and it returns on it's own it is shown as the process /usr/bin/rhythmbox.  I don't see any server.